# Rails Devise + Devise-bascamper How to allow super user to login to any account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, subdomain

I'm using devise and [devise-basecamper](https://github.com/digitalopera/devise-basecamper) for authentication with my subdomain based web app.

I would like to allow super users to access any of the accounts (basically any subdomain).

I'm not sure how i would go about implementing this so that a user can be authenticated into any subdomain since a user is currently validated against a specific subdomain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I had to remove the unique email index from the users table which devise creates by default, and add a new unique index on the users table with both the `email`, and `account_id` columns. This will allow me to create a user (which i'm calling support@example.com) for every account that is created.

Here's my migration

```
def change
  remove_index :users, :email
  add_index :users, [:email, :account_id], :unique => true
end
```

Here's my `after_save` callback that i added to my `account` model.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :create_support_user

  private 

  # A callback that creates a support user after an account is created.
  def create_support_user   

    user = User.new
    user.email = "support@example.com"
    user.password = "test1234"
    user.password_confirmation = "test1234"
    user.account_id = self.id
    user.name = "Support"
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.admin = true
    user.save

  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understood correctly your needs, the st approach is to perform the following steps:

- as an admin be able to "become" another user, in order to access your application as if you used his credential to log-in
- After "becoming" this user you want to be able to "become" your real user back again whenever you want without having to log-out and log-in again.
- Keep your admin privileges while you became another user (see bottom of the answer for this)
- Avoid logs to mention action was perform by the user you "became"

**Becoming user**

This is necessary if you need to perform actions as another user, or "see what he sees"

First you need to implement the devise's official way (this is **pseudo-code**, I let you adapt it to your personal situation)

```
# the usage of session[:original_user_id] is explained later
def become
  if admin? or session[:original_user_id]

    if session[:original_user_id] == params[:id]
      session[:original_user_id] = nil # This is intended to clean-up stuff after you become your self back again
    else
      session[:original_user_id] = current_user.id # This is to record your real identity while you are becoming some one else
    end

    sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

As you see, we "become" the requested user, plus we record in session your real `user.id`. Note that if you choose this solution you MUST set-up rails to save session data in database, to avoid avoid having those data roaming around in wild cookies.

**Becoming your self back again**

Second you need somewhere in your view a link to "become back your self", I suggest header as a good location

```
if session[:original_user_id]
  link_to 'Be my self', become_path(session[:original_user_id])
end
```

This will create a link, visible only for admin that "became" someone else, and the link will allow you to "become" the user with ID that correspond to your real user account. Clicking on it will bring back your real identity.

**Keep your admin privileges while you became another user**

Then you want to keep you admin privilege, we need to cheat the system to make him believe that the user you "became" is an admin, but we must protect the application so it won't do unwanted save of this "fake privilege" in the database

In your application controller, implement a before filter

```
before_filter :fake_admin

def fake_admin
  if session[:original_user_id]
    current_user.fake_admin = true
    current_user.admin = true
  end
end
```

Then to protect you user record to gain unwanted admin privilege, in your user model you can set a before_save_filter (or before_validation_filter, depending on your architecture)

```
before_save :check_for_fake_admin

def check_for_fake_admin
  self.admin = false if self.fake_admin
end
```

**Avoid logs to mention the name of the user you became**

You have no choice than manually hack all places in your application where an action needs to mention the admin name instead of the user you "became"'s name. Axample in records `updated_by` must be set to `session[:original_user_id]` if it is not nil

Now that's needed not only in the logs, but for any other thing. It all depend on your application and it can become very tedious to maintain.

**Disclamer**

- This is pseudo code, unsecure and if you choose this solution you would need to enforce security
- I answer to your question because you asked, but my personal piece of advise is: do not implement this solution, cause it looks like a big security hole, and you should let admin user to log-out and log-in after they become someone else

Comment: I only read your first bullet point, but you are misunderstanding (or i'm mis-explaining). I want to be able to login to ANY account (any subdomain) with my 1 and only single admin user. I want to do things and have my logs show that I did them(not log them as another user).

Comment: Read the rest, you cannot snap your fingers and become another user while keeping your admin privileges, you need to set-up a whole system, and part of it is to be able to change account, that is what I explain to you. Your case is complicated, that's why my answer is long, but its complete. I spent time to write it, be kind and spend a bit of time to read it, then you can trash it if you don't like it :) Cheers and good luck

Comment: Also, if you want to act as "jeff" you need to be "jeff", so your `current_user` need to be "jeff". Off course your whole application will see you as "jeff", so the logs will mention "jeff" and not "admin", for that and other inconvenient stuff you need to hack by hand (check for the session variable for example). You are not looking at heavy and complicated solution

Comment: Please define "log in to jeff's account". Without any detail what I understand is "become jeff" from the application point of view.

Comment: I'm not trashing your answer, i just thought right off the bat you didn't understand what i'm looking for. I don't want to become another user. I want to be my user and be able to log in to jeff's account. I also want to be my user and be able to login to dick, harry, and larry's accounts as well, but since they have different subdomains I can't because in my user table, my user is associated with 1 account.

Comment: Are you familiar with `devise-basecamper`? That's what i'm using.

Comment: Now I do :) But I must be missing something cause I still don't see how my technique cannot apply.

Comment: Your technique probably would work, but i don't want to impersonate another user. I just want to use the single user that i have, and login to any account with it.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following solution within my apps.

```
class RandomController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, unless: :super_user
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def super_user?
    current_user.email == 'super@example.com'
  end
end
```

Comment: Where do you define your super_user method?

Comment: This doesn't work. How can `super_user?` get the `current_user.email `if the user has NOT been authenticated? If the user had not been authenticated, there is no current_user.

Comment: @Catfish see my edit - this will work. If a user is not authenticated it will require login, if is signed in and super user it will let him in.

Comment: I just tried this again and it does not work. Your solution does not take into account that a user is tied to a specific subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

The devise documentation has a section [How To: Sign in as another user if you are an admin](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin), which explains how to achieve what you are trying to do.

This is the gist of what the documentation says you need to do:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter authenticate_user!

  def become
    return unless current_user.is_an_admin?
    sign_in(:user, User.find(params[:id]))
    redirect_to root_url # or user_root_url
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not trying to sign in as another user, i'm trying to allow an admin user to sign in to any account.

Comment: That's what the section of the documentation that I linked to is explaining how to do... it is for allowing an admin user to sign in to any account.

Comment: From the looks of the title and the code, it signs a user in as another user rather than allowing a single user to be able to access any account. For example if i'm user "admin" and there is user "jeff" linked to account "A", i want to be able to sign in to account "A" as user "admin", but the link and code that you posted would allow user "admin" to sign in as user "jeff". I want to keep the distinction so that "admin" can't do something and the logs show that "jeff" did it. Please correct me if i'm misunderstanding the code.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication and Authorization are two different actions and I'm of the opinion that it has to be done separately. Use devise method for authentication, and implement your custom code for authorization.

**Example:**

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :authorize_user

end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def authorize_user
    unless current_user.admin? or request.subdomain == current_user.subdomain# logic to check if user is authorized
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Access denied"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This will not let me login to any other account, other than the account that my name is associated with. I need to be able to login to ANY account, but i can't create my username for every account as you can't have duplicate emails with devise. Make sense?

Comment: You dont need to create separate accounts. Any user for whom `current_user.admin` returns `true` will be authorized.

Comment: I know that, but i can't use the same user for more than 1 account beacause devise won't let you create users with duplicate emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to split authorization and authentication. Authentication validates if a certain login account is valid, Authorization assigns a set of resources to the user.

If I have generic authorization, you can just make a method in the ApplicationController that returns a (filtered)resource if the user has access to it. Or you can for example add a scope to every active record model that scopes by user_id if the user has only rights to see his own resources.

Comment: All authorization aside, I can't login to another account. I'm using `devise-basecamper`.